# Insert CLOB into Oracle database from SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to insert the same long string into all cells in certain column, which is CLOB type.

It said I should use "bind variables" to do it. So i Googled this:

```
variable xmlstuff CLOB;
exec :xmlstuff := '<?xml version="1.0"?> ... really long xml...';

UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET COLUMN_NAME = '&&xmlstuff';
```

Now it still says

```
The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
```

What is the proper use of bind variable in this case?

Comment: `&&xmlstuff` is not a bind variable, by the way.

Comment: Why are you working with XML as a CLOB and not as XMLType?

Comment: @evenro: Because of previous programmers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are programming using C# or Java - just use the OracleCLOB object, and it will do all the necessary steps.

If you want to use a CLOB in SQL or PL/SQL, 
you need to allocate it, and release it after using.
search for DBMS_LOB information.

Regarding the 4000 bytes limit - this is a varchar2 limit within SQL. 
to bypass this - you can use PL/SQL - which limits you to a varchar of 32KB, which is not as near to the 4GB that you can hold in a CLOB, but that is the limit for "automatic" creation of a CLOB.
if your string is longer than 32K - you'll have to use a DBMS_LOB to load the data into the clog object, by using append on the clob object.

this is the fastest link I found about how to do it: http://geekswithblogs.net/robertphyatt/archive/2010/03/24/write-read-and-update-oracle-clobs-with-plsql.aspx

I wanted to answer fast, so please let me know if you cannot solve your issue after getting this information - and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Whoa, that looks hard. I thought the answer is gonna be something like "Just add this line into the SQL script and it will work."

Comment: Sorry :( For short strings it works - but for things that are bigger than the limits- you need to work harder...

Comment: Thanks anyway. This may help somebody who thinks the same as i did.

Comment: Just for clarification - it is 4000 bytes limit (just fixed it above) - for languages that each character is 2 bytes, it'll be 2000 chars... (important to be accurate..)